# Gnome shell extensions - "Status Area Horizontal Spacing" resets the spacing when I hover my mouse over it

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

When I'm using the above mentioned extension to customize my Gnome desktop (shell version 3.36.4), as soon as I close the tweaks settings and hover my mouse over the status area, the icons padding resets to default.

After a little hit and trial, I figured out that "Smart transparent topbar", this extension was the culprit and causing the issue, after disabling this extension, the status area spacing works perfectly.